# Image Manipulation - add image with corners in exact positions

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an image which is a background containing a boxed area like this:

[image: Distorted trapezium]

I know the exact positions of the corners of that shape, and I'd like to place another image within it. (So it appears to be inside the box).

I'm aware of the drawImage method for HTML5 canvas, but it seems to only support x, y, width, height parameters rather than exact coordinates. How might I draw an image onto a canvas at a specific set of coordinates, and ideally have the browser itself handle stretching the image.

Comment: Can you show your "MCVE" ([mcve]) HTML and CSS? Show what you've used to get to this point, and, ideally, show your attempted solution. That way we can give a relevant answer (without guessing) and explain where your code went wrong, so you can learn. As can future users from this question and its answers.

Comment: Have you considered using CSS Transforms?

Comment: Not possible in 2D canvas as the transform used can only create parallelograms (opposite sides always parallel) you will need to use WebGL instead where you have almost full access to the GPU. If you only need to display the image then as suggested CSS would be best. Or you could try creating your own scan line render for 2D canvas but that will be far from realtime.

Comment: Oh I forgot to say. Having the position of the 4 corners will not give you what you want (guessing fitting image to a scene) as 3D projections are dependent on field of view (eqiv camera focal length). Without that info you will find it difficult to match the perspective, not of the points but of the texture mapping.

Comment: You can "fake" perspective by offsetting & resizing vertical slices of your image. Here's an example from a previous Stackoverflow [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709306/crop-the-image-in-irregular-shape-and-stretch-it/25712001#25712001). The advantage of this method over CSS transforms is that you can then convert the perspective canvas drawing into an image element The disadvantage is that you are somewhat limited to adjusting your image either vertically or horizontally -- doing both requires (often disappointing) multiple pixel interpolation.

Comment: @Blindman67 4 corners are completely sufficient to compute the transform because you don't actually need a full 3-d transform (3x3), only a projective one (homogeneous coordinates), so there are only 8 degrees of freedom and the problem has a single unique solution (unless the 4 corners are colinear).

Comment: @szym  You are correct, but that is not what I was attempting to point out. Assuming the OP is trying to match a real world scene he will need either the image aspect or the focal length, because if the image aspect is incorrect it will not appear to fit the scene, event though it fits the 4 points. Parallax will amplify any mis-match.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Quadrilateral transform

One way to go about this is to use Quadrilateral transforms. They are different than 3D transforms and would allow you to draw to a canvas in case you want to export the result.

The example shown here is simplified and uses basic sub-divison and "cheats" on the rendering itself - that is, it draws in a small square instead of the shape of the sub-divided cell but because of the small size and the overlap we can get away with it in many non-extreme cases.

The proper way would be to split the shape into two triangles, then scan pixel wise in the destination bitmap, map the point from destination triangle to source triangle. If the position value was fractional you would use that to determine pixel interpolation (f.ex. bi-linear 2x2 or bi-cubic 4x4).

I do not intend to cover all this in this answer as it would quickly become out of scope for the SO format, but the method would probably be suitable in this case unless you need to animate it (it is not performant enough for that if you want high resolution).

## Method

Lets start with an initial quadrilateral shape:

[image: Initial quad]

The first step is to interpolate the Y-positions on each bar C1-C4 and C2-C3. We're gonna need current position as well as next position. We'll use linear interpolation ("lerp") for this using a normalized value for `t`:

```
y1current = lerp( C1, C4, y / height)
y2current = lerp( C2, C3, y / height)

y1next = lerp(C1, C4, (y + step) / height)
y2next = lerp(C2, C3, (y + step) / height)
```

This gives us a new line between and along the outer vertical bars.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qAWUK4B.png]

Next we need the X positions on that line, both current and next. This will give us four positions we will fill with current pixel, either as-is or interpolate it (not shown here):

```
p1 = lerp(y1current, y2current, x / width)
p2 = lerp(y1current, y2current, (x + step) / width)
p3 = lerp(y1next, y2next, (x + step) / width)
p4 = lerp(y1next, y2next, x / width)
```

`x` and `y` will be the position in the source image using integer values.

[image: Iterating x/y]

We can use this setup inside a loop that will iterate over each pixel in the source bitmap.

## Demo

The demo can be found at the bottom of the answer. Move the circular handles around to transform and play with the step value to see its impact on performance and result.

The demo *will* have moire and other artifacts, but as mentioned earlier that would be a topic for another day.

***Snapshot from demo:***

[image: Demo snapshot]

## Alternative methods

You can also use WebGL or Three.js to setup a 3D environment and render to canvas. Here is a link to the latter solution:

- **[Three.js](https://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/)**

and an example of how to use texture mapped surface:

- **[Three.js texturing](http://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/webgl-and-three-js-texture-mappi-1/)** (instead of defining a cube, just define one place/face).

Using this approach will enable you to export the result to a canvas or an image as well, but for performance a GPU is required on the client.

If you don't need to export or manipulate the result I would suggest to use simple CSS 3D transform as shown in the other answers.

```js
/* Quadrilateral Transform - (c) Ken Nilsen, CC3.0-Attr */
var img = new Image();  img.onload = go;
img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/EWoZkZm.jpg";

function go() {
  var me = this,
      stepEl = document.querySelector("input"),
      stepTxt = document.querySelector("span"),
      c = document.querySelector("canvas"),
      ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
      corners = [
        {x: 100, y: 20},           // ul
        {x: 520, y: 20},           // ur
        {x: 520, y: 380},          // br
        {x: 100, y: 380}           // bl
      ],
      radius = 10, cPoint, timer,  // for mouse handling
      step = 4;                    // resolution

  update();

  // render image to quad using current settings
  function render() {
  
    var p1, p2, p3, p4, y1c, y2c, y1n, y2n,
        w = img.width - 1,         // -1 to give room for the "next" points
        h = img.height - 1;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    for(y = 0; y < h; y += step) {
      for(x = 0; x < w; x += step) {
        y1c = lerp(corners[0], corners[3],  y / h);
        y2c = lerp(corners[1], corners[2],  y / h);
        y1n = lerp(corners[0], corners[3], (y + step) / h);
        y2n = lerp(corners[1], corners[2], (y + step) / h);

        // corners of the new sub-divided cell p1 (ul) -> p2 (ur) -> p3 (br) -> p4 (bl)
        p1 = lerp(y1c, y2c,  x / w);
        p2 = lerp(y1c, y2c, (x + step) / w);
        p3 = lerp(y1n, y2n, (x + step) / w);
        p4 = lerp(y1n, y2n,  x / w);

        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, step, step,  p1.x, p1.y, // get most coverage for w/h:
            Math.ceil(Math.max(step, Math.abs(p2.x - p1.x), Math.abs(p4.x - p3.x))) + 1,
            Math.ceil(Math.max(step, Math.abs(p1.y - p4.y), Math.abs(p2.y - p3.y))) + 1)
      }
    }
  }
  
  function lerp(p1, p2, t) {
    return {
      x: p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) * t, 
      y: p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) * t}
  }

  /* Stuff for demo: -----------------*/
  function drawCorners() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#09f"; 
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    // border
    for(var i = 0, p; p = corners[i++];) ctx[i ? "lineTo" : "moveTo"](p.x, p.y);
    ctx.closePath();
    // circular handles
    for(i = 0; p = corners[i++];) {
      ctx.moveTo(p.x + radius, p.y); 
      ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, radius, 0, 6.28);
    }
    ctx.stroke()
  }
 
  function getXY(e) {
    var r = c.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {x: e.clientX - r.left, y: e.clientY - r.top}
  }
 
  function inCircle(p, pos) {
    var dx = pos.x - p.x,
        dy = pos.y - p.y;
    return dx*dx + dy*dy <= radius * radius
  }

  // handle mouse
  c.onmousedown = function(e) {
    var pos = getXY(e);
    for(var i = 0, p; p = corners[i++];) {if (inCircle(p, pos)) {cPoint = p; break}}
  }
  window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (cPoint) {
      var pos = getXY(e);
      cPoint.x = pos.x; cPoint.y = pos.y;
      cancelAnimationFrame(timer);
      timer = requestAnimationFrame(update.bind(me))
    }
  }
  window.onmouseup = function() {cPoint = null}
  
  stepEl.oninput = function() {
    stepTxt.innerHTML = (step = Math.pow(2, +this.value));
    update();
  }
  
  function update() {render(); drawCorners()}
}
```

```css
body {margin:20px;font:16px sans-serif}
canvas {border:1px solid #000;margin-top:10px}
```

```html
<label>Step: <input type=range min=0 max=5 value=2></label><span>4</span><br>
<canvas width=620 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: Cool approach! Do you know if there is any performance advantage to using a lerp style approach over a vector approach? (I'm doing something similar to you, but using vectors)

Comment: This is exactly the code I needed, but unfortunately, the image as seen in the preview is drawing past the blue line on the right and bottom sides. I can't quite work out what part of the code does this, would you be able to fix the original code? When the step resolution is increased this is even more prevalent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS Transforms to make your image look like that box. For example:

```css
img {
  margin: 50px;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(20deg) rotateX(20deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200">
```

Read more about [CSS Transforms on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

Comment: The draggable points from the first answer is exactly what I need but using CSS perspective is a much better approach, I'm trying to combine the quadrilateral X and Y inputs to something the CSS transform can understand, has anyone experience with this? For me personally this would be the ultimate solution for this thread.

Answer (score 0):

This solution relies on the browser performing the compositing. You put the image that you want warped in a separate element, overlaying the background using `position: absolute`.

Then use CSS `transform` property to apply any perspective transform to the overlay element.

To find the transform matrix you can use the answer from: [How to match 3D perspective of real photo and object in CSS3 3D transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050537/how-to-match-3d-perspective-of-real-photo-and-object-in-css3-3d-transforms/36217808#36217808)